# Vagrant Synced Folder without reload?

Tags: vagrant

I have a file on my host located at `~/ansible/provisioning/playbook.yml` that corresponds to `/vagrant/provisioning/playbook.yml` on the guest. Every time I make changes to the file on the host, the changes do not show up on the guest unless I run `vagrant reload` which completely restarts the VirtualBox VM. Is there another way to get files to sync in real time using another filesystem type (NFS perhaps)? My host is MacOS, guest is CentOS 7. I am using vagrant version 2.0.0.

Edit:

I have included my `Vagrantfile` on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CkuLZ6Nb). Yes, it appears I am using `rsync`.

```
$ cat .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/synced_folders 
{"rsync":{"/vagrant":{"type":"rsync","guestpath":"/vagrant","hostpath":"/Users/timothy/Desktop/code/ansible","disabled":false,"__vagrantfile":true,"owner":"vagrant","group":"vagrant"}}}
```

In addtion to adding `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"` to my Vagrantfile, I also had to run
`$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

Comment: the shared folder is probably typed with rsync, can you give your Vagrantfile for review ?

Comment: I have provided the Vagrantfile. Sorry it took so long. I was sleeping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as thought rsync is enabled, the box `centos/7` has rsync by default, this has been discussed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40975301/4296747)

When using rsync, you can turn the [rsync-auto](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync-auto.html) command to automatically push any new changes from the host to the VM.

If you want to use default virtual box shared folder feature, you can add the following in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
```

Comment: This worked, although I then had to run `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` to install missing kernel modules and virtualbox drivers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-build/issues/27) on github the fastest solution is to use [geerlingguy/centos7](https://app.vagrantup.com/geerlingguy/boxes/centos7) box.

This box will build the guest additions.

Tested - works smoothly!